# Vue error on casl + vue when registering Can component globally

Tags: typescript, vue.js, casl

I have created a simple vue + typescript app with vue-cli.
Following [https://stalniy.github.io/casl/v4/en/package/casl-vue](https://stalniy.github.io/casl/v4/en/package/casl-vue#getting-started) instructions I have declared the following:

```
// main.ts
import Vue from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';
import { abilitiesPlugin } from '@casl/vue';
import ability from './services/ability';
import { Can } from '@casl/vue';

Vue.config.productionTip = false;
Vue.use(abilitiesPlugin);
Vue.component('Can', Can);
new Vue({
    render: h => h(App)
    // ability
}).$mount('#app');
```

But I get the error on second parameter on:

```
 Vue.component('Can', Can);
```

> No overload matches this call.
>     The last overload gave the following error.
>       Argument of type 'FunctionalComponentOptions, PropsDefinition>>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ComponentOptions, DefaultMethods, DefaultComputed, PropsDefinition>, Record<...>>'.
>         Types of property 'render' are incompatible.
>           Type '((this: undefined, createElement: CreateElement, context: RenderContext>) => VNode | VNode[]) | undefined' is not assignable to type '((createElement: CreateElement, hack: RenderContext>) => VNode) | undefined'.
>             Type '(this: undefined, createElement: CreateElement, context: RenderContext>) => VNode | VNode[]' is not assignable to type '(createElement: CreateElement, hack: RenderContext>) => VNode'.
>               Type 'VNode | VNode[]' is not assignable to type 'VNode'.
>                 Type 'VNode[]' is missing the following properties from type 'VNode': isRootInsert, isCommentts(2769)
>   vue.d.ts(112, 3): The last overload is declared here.

My package.json contains:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@casl/ability": "^4.0.5",
    "@casl/vue": "^1.0.2",
    "@typegoose/typegoose": "^6.4.0",
    "mongoose": "^5.9.9",
    "vue": "^2.6.11",
    "vue-class-component": "^7.2.3",
    "vue-property-decorator": "^8.4.1"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@types/mongoose": "^5.7.12",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^2.26.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^2.26.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.3.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-typescript": "~4.3.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.3.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-prettier": "^6.0.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-typescript": "^5.0.2",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.2.2",
    "lint-staged": "^9.5.0",
    "prettier": "^1.19.1",
    "typescript": "~3.8.3",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11"
},
```

Thanks in advance for any help on this. Sorry if I'm missing some info on this Q post (is my first one).

Comment: Looks like this is a bug. Use `Vue.component('Can', Can as any)`, I'm working on the vue-todo example in TypeScript, so will send here a link to that tomorrow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Author of CASL here. I improved typescript types for `@casl/vue`, updated docs and released a patch version for `@casl/vue`.

Also you can find an example of vue + casl + typescript integration in this repo https://github.com/stalniy/casl-examples/tree/master/packages/vue-todo

Comment: I have no reputation to upvote this (public in the score), but it was what I was looking for. Thanks and keep the good work, casl is a great library.